# Tomcat / Servlet: How to install certificates without restart

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ssl, keystore

I'm doing multi domain virtual hosting with one Tomcat application. The domains I use are stored in a database. The app works well enough so that I don't have to restart tomcat in normal operation.

The problem is: Everytime I add a new domain for https to work I have to add another ip-address and a certificate in server.xml and do a restart.

I would like to get rid of the restarts.

So is there a way to add (ip-addresses / certificates) to tomcat without restarting it?

I would consider anything from an "Tomcat Manager App Plus" to patching the keystore and tomcats connector or even using another Servlet Container if it's capable of doing this.
(While the best solution for me would be something where I could store all my certs in the database because I already have a managing app for that)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to be clear: I'm currently using one webapp with multiple connectors. The webapp decides which content to deliver based on the request url.

Answer (score -1):

if we do any changes in server.xml in tomcat we should restart server to update settings..